# Why is a part of my table open?

Tags: tables

Though I adjusted the width of the table, a part of it is open, as shown in the picture. The code is attached. Kindly help me. I have faced this issue before as well, so kindly tell why this arises typically.
[image: Table]

```
$\begin{tabular}[H]{|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.07 \textwidth}|p{0.07 \textwidth}|p{0.07 \textwidth}|}
\hline
Parameters & Si CMOS & 4H-SiC CMOS& GaN HEMT\\
 & \\
\hline
Critical Electrical Field (MV/cm) & 0.3 & 3 & 3.5\\
\hline
Energy Bandgap (eV) & 1.12 & 3.23 & 3.4 \\
\hline
Electron Mobility ( \ $ cm^2/(V s) $ & 500 & 35 & 1500 \\
\hline
Electron Saturation Velocity ($10^7 cm/s $) & 1 & 1.8 & 3.4\\
\hline
Thermal Conductivity (W/(K cm)) & 1.3& 3.7 & 1.5 \\
\hline
Melting Point (K) & 1412 & 3103 & 2500 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}\\
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `& \\ ` is a 2-cell row, you want `& & & \\ `

Comment: Or, just delete the ` & \\` line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beside use siunitx (omitted here in order to not mess the MWE)  to fit the width of the whole table without headaches, consider use `tabulary` or `tabularx` (in this case, better the first) and on the other hand, avoid vertical rules using `booktabs`, not to hide cell gaps, but to improve it to a more readable formal style (not just a matter of taste, as this is mandatory style standard in many journals because is more readable).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs} %\defaultaddspace1em
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{@{}LCCC@{}}
\toprule\vspace{0pt} 
Parameters & Si CMOS & 4H-SiC  CMOS& GaN HEMT\\\midrule
Critical Electrical Field    (MV/cm) & 0.3 & 3 & 3.5\\\addlinespace
Energy Bandgap (eV) & 1.12 & 3.23 & 3.4 \\\addlinespace
Electron Mobility (cm\textsuperscript{2}/(V s)) & 500 & 35 & 1500 \\\addlinespace
Electron Saturation Velocity ($10^7$ cm/s) & 1 & 1.8 & 3.4\\\addlinespace
Thermal Conductivity (W/(K cm)) & 1.3& 3.7 & 1.5 \\\addlinespace
Melting Point (K) & 1412 & 3103 & 2500 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

To fill in the gaps in two of the four vertical lines, you need to change the line  `& \\` located immediately below the header line to  `& & & \\`. Or, just delete this line.

I would also recommend that you use the machinery of the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package -- specifically, its `\unit` and `\qty` macros -- to typeset scientific units and their associated quantities.

And, instead of setting the column widths as a fraction of the overall width of the text block (the parameter `\textwidth` varies from document class to document class), I'd choose the column widths based on the absolute width of specific words that need to fit unbroken in a cell. In the code below, that's "4H-SiC" for the three data columns. For the left-hand column, two possible widths are considered: "Conductivity" for the table shown in the upper part, and "Critical Electrical " for the table in the lower part. The tables' overall *widths* aren't hugely different; however, their total heights -- 21 rows in the upper table, and only 14 in the lower table -- differ considerably.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}      % for 'm' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\RaggedRight` macro
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx} % for '\unit' and '\qty' macros

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less cramped "look"

%% determine widths of column 1 and columns 2 thru 4
\newlength\mylenAa
\settowidth\mylenAa{Conductivity}
\newlength\mylenAb
\settowidth\mylenAb{Critical Electrical }
\newlength\mylenB
\settowidth\mylenB{4H-SiC}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
% version 1
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}m{\mylenAa}|
                 >{\centering}m{\mylenB}|
                 >{\centering}m{\mylenB}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylenB}|}
\hline
Parameters & Si CMOS & 4H-SiC CMOS& GaN HEMT\\
% & & & \\ % <-- two more instances of "&"
\hline
Critical Electrical Field 
(\unit{\mega\volt\per\centi\meter}) & 0.3 & 3.0 & 3.5\\
\hline
Energy Bandgap 
(\unit{\electronvolt}) & 1.12 & 3.23 & 3.4 \\
\hline
Electron Mobility 
(\unit{\centi\meter\squared\per\volt\per\second}) & 500 & 35 & 1500 \\
\hline
Electron Saturation Velocity 
(\qty{e7}{\centi\meter\per\second}) & 1.0 & 1.8 & 3.4\\
\hline
Thermal Conductivity 
(\unit{\watt\per\kelvin\per\centi\meter}) & 1.3& 3.7 & 1.5 \\
\hline
Melting Point 
(\unit{\kelvin}) & 1412 & 3103 & 2500 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
% version 2
\begin{tabular}{|>{\RaggedRight}m{\mylenAb}| % <-- bigger width
                 >{\centering}m{\mylenB}|
                 >{\centering}m{\mylenB}|
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\mylenB}|}
\hline
Parameters & Si CMOS & 4H-SiC CMOS& GaN HEMT\\
\hline
Critical Electrical Field 
(\unit{\mega\volt\per\centi\meter}) & 0.3 & 3.0 & 3.5\\
\hline
Energy Bandgap 
(\unit{\electronvolt}) & 1.12 & 3.23 & 3.4 \\
\hline
Electron Mobility 
(\unit{\centi\meter\squared\per\volt\per\second}) & 500 & 35 & 1500 \\
\hline
Electron Saturation Velocity 
(\qty{e7}{\centi\meter\per\second}) & 1.0 & 1.8 & 3.4\\
\hline
Thermal Conductivity 
(\unit{\watt\per\kelvin\per\centi\meter}) & 1.3& 3.7 & 1.5 \\
\hline
Melting Point 
(\unit{\kelvin}) & 1412 & 3103 & 2500 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```